# Could not convert string to float error, giving names numbers in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

Using a csv file I need to let the user input a number and get back the number of times the actress has been nominated for an award. This data is in rows on the csv file.

This is the code I thought would work to give a output of the name then I was going to use this to return the nomination number.

```py
import csv
data=csv.reader(open('Nominees_18.csv','r'))
print('Names of acresses: Sally Hawkins (1), Frances McDormand (2), Saorise Ronan (3), Margot Robbie (4), Meryl Streep (5)')

names=[]
checkn=int(input('Check Name? '))
for row in data:
    names.append(float(row[checkn]))
```

Program output:

```
Names of acresses: Sally Hawkins (1), Frances McDormand (2), Saorise Ronan (3), Margot Robbie (4), Meryl Streep (5)
Check Name? 2

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-a676aea80b01> in <module>()
      7 checkn=int(input('Check Name? '))
      8 for row in data:
----> 9     names.append(float(row[checkn]))

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'y'
```

Comment: Share Nominees_18.csv please

Comment: The value at `row[checkn]` is a string, where `checkn` is the index for the list `row`. A string cannot be converted to float. Remove the float() conversion and it should be okay.

Comment: Your `row[checkn]` is `y` which can't converted to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this

**Solution:**

```
import csv
names=[]
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

     print('Names of acresses: Sally Hawkins (1), Frances McDormand (2), Saorise Ronan (3), Margot Robbie (4), Meryl Streep (5)')

     checkn=int(input('Check Name? '))
     for row in data:
         names.append(float(row[checkn]))
```

If you show your exact CSV file structure and an example I can test it also. above code solve your problem that good otherwise comment below